# Tank block - How to have actions on above different amounts?

Tags: anylogic

I have a tank block that is configured to trigger an action on above a certain threshold, but I would like to add another action to trigger on above another (higher) threshold, e.g., 1 and 50 tons.

My initial thought was to add an if statement in the code block to check if the amount was above 50, and if so to trigger the corresponding action, however the code is only executed once upon crossing the (smaller) 'on above' threshold, and the condition will not be checked multiple times as the storage stays above this smaller threshold. Any ideas on how I might be able to get around this? Thanks in advance! [image: Example of what I want to do]

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a cyclic event that checks your amount continuously and executes code when the 2nd threshold is hit. Also not too elegant but absolutely possible

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: SOLVED, but not elegantly

You can make a duplicate tank with a fluidConvert to fluidSplit so that the original fluid input is doubled and split evenly between both tanks. Then you can trigger separate actions for on above different thresholds in each tank.

For 2 thresholds you need to specify a factor of 2 in fluidConvert, a factor of 3 with 3 tanks for 3 different action thresholds, and so on. Also, if any fluid leaves the tank then you need a following fluidMerge with .5/.5 proportions and a fluidConvert with a factor of .5 to remove fluid evenly from both tanks so that their utilizations are always equal.

This is not an ideal solution though, so if anyone has a better way to do it I would love to know.
[image]